# Will stack.yaml of library ignored in main program?

Tags: haskell

My main Haskell program has a `stack.yaml` file that specifies, among other things, a Stack resolver.

The main program makes use of libraries that each have their own `stack.yaml` where different Stack resolvers are used.

So the question is, when I compile my main program with `stack build`, which Stack resolver is actually used? Only the one for the main program, or all of them at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one for your project is used. The packages and versions available to you are those available in the snapshot referred to by the resolver specified in your project's `stack.yaml`. You will have to set `extra-deps` if you want packages or versions not available in that snapshot.